# Save NSURL's PDF Locally - Retrieve

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, nsdictionary, nsurl

***Hello,***

How would I retrieve an `NSUrl`'s `PDF` locally from a `NSDictionary`. I save it like so:

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[
    NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/info.pdf"]];

// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

But how would I retrieve the file and display it in a `UIWebView`??

Cheers,
SebOH

Comment: Are you saving it to disk for a reason? Is your intention to check if it's there and no download again? Have you debugged your code to see what works and what doesn't?

Comment: Done all that. My reason being I don't want to load data every time the page loads.

Comment: Not clear what do you need. Does your code work? If yes, what else do you want to do?

Comment: I want to retrieve the data that is being saved using the code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the exact thing, "retrieve the file and display it in a UIWebView??" using the below code

```
// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Is there some problem you are facing with the above lines of code, is the PDF loading in the webview?

So if you don't want to download the file every time do this check,

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
//download the file
}
```

So the whole solution would be

```
// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        //download the file
        NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[
        NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/info.pdf"]];
        [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. Once you downloaded the file you don't need to download every time. you can access the directory where the file has been stored.

```
 // Store the Data locally as PDF File
        NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
                                                                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                                                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
                                                                      ]];


        NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[
                                                                 NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/info.pdf"]];
        [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        }


        // Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView setDelegate:self];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```